# Is there a library that mimics all the functionality of Matlab in Java?

Tags: java, matlab, open-source

Is there an Open Source library that has all the functionality of Matlab, with advance high level functions, but purely done in java?

Edit: Some people are misunderstanding what Im getting at.

I'm looking for a LIBRARY of functions that will mimic matlab, so no matlab syntax. (maybe there is an object that will take care of all the duck typing)  Java language with matlab power/functionality.

Answer (score 3):

**All** the functionality of MATLAB? No, there isn't.

There are some numerical libraries for Java. However, the coverage isn't anywhere near as extensive as MATLAB's. Also, arguably, the language itself isn't terribly well-suited for things like computational linear algebra (for example, lack of operator overloading makes any matrix manipulation code pretty hard to read).

For some pointers, see [Java Numerics](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/).

Answer (score 1):

Try Mathworks - http://www.mathworks.in/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f44062.html

or jMatlab. link - http://www.jmathlib.de

Answer (score 1):

I think not; 
Octave is a MatLab look-a-like (not really a library) but is written in C++ (http://www.gnu.org/software/octave)
For some numerical libraries see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#Java